# ERROR "Segmentation fault (core dumped)"

Tags: linux, gdb, coredump

[`*Segmentation fault*`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xyrnt.png)
[`*mkidir /etc/reaver*`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0lW5p.png)

I have a problem. I have an OS Linux Fedora 26. I am trying to work in Reaver with my Network Adapter Alfa Awus036h. When I run the command `wash -i`, I get this error: `segmentation fault (core dumped)`.

File `mkdir /etc/reaver` is present. Аlso drove the `wash -i wlp0s20u1mon -C` command, also does not help.

**How can I fix it?**

Comment: Segmentation faults are a pain.  Basically the `wash` command is breaking.  It's not giving you (or us) any information to go on.

Comment: and what information is needed

Comment: Information you are not being given.  This might be a bug in `wash`. It might be a that you have the wrong version. It might that the program is corrupt. It might be that other libraries that wash relies on ar the wrong version.  All you are told is the program code tried to do something impossible and the opperating system was forced to kill the program as a result.  This shouldnt normally happen.

Comment: Okay how to find out this information?

Comment: This may not be solvable. Check youve got the right version of reaver for your os.  To debug it yourself your would need to get a copy of the `wash` source code, compile it yorself then step through with a line-by-line debugger. Thats not going to be easy and not sometging we can help you with.

Answer (score 1):

There is [a bug report](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1487467) and [FAF report](https://retrace.fedoraproject.org/faf/reports/1797721/), most likely for SIGSEGV you are getting. Unfortunately there are no workarounds in bug report and the bug is yet unresolved. Now you can only wait for it to be fixed or probably try to fix it yourself.

Comment: And now what i can do?